# How to get constraintView to fill width space inside scrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraintLayout inside a scrollView as shown below and the constraintLayout does not fill the screen in terms of width. How can I get it to do so ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_leg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/leg"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leg1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/leg"
       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/title_leg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_leg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leg2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/leg"
       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leg1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/leg1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


 </ScrollView>
```

Here is a screenshot, it does look fine in the Android Studio design tool but not on the phone I use for emulation sake:

[image]

Comment: the above code looks absolutely fine please provide a screenshot to make us understand better.

Comment: Here you go (Sorry, i'm not very familiar with the new constraintView so I thought it was an obvious error in that regards)

Comment: ConstraintLayout children don't really need gravity. You can do everything with constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly like below

[image]

then please check this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_leg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="leg"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leg1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="leg"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/title_leg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_leg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leg2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="leg"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leg1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/leg1" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```